# Extract data from one sheet to another based of criteria

Tags: excel, vba, macros, advanced-filter

I am trying to figure out how to extract only certain data from sheet1 if the Total Pickup Time or the Total Delivery Time is greater than 0 to sheet2.  I have attached pictures of the sheets and example data that will be included.  I know how to do a macro with advanced filter but I am unsure how to handle this one because on sheet on the headers are on the side in column a instead of being at the top.

Thanks

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78wm5.png)

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjdIK.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sh1 as Worksheet
Dim sh2 as Worksheet
Dim sh1x, sh2y as Ineteger  'You have to set sh1x to the column you want to check & sh2y to the row you want the data to be transfered to


Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Audit")
Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Wait Time")

If sh1.Cells(20, sh1x).Value > 1 or sh1.Cells(21, sh1x).Value > 1 then
   sh2.Cells(sh2y, 1) = sh1.Cells(2, sh1x)
   sh2.Cells(sh2y, 2) = sh1.Cells(3, sh1x)
   sh2.Cells(sh2y, 3) = sh1.Cells(4, sh1x)
   sh2.Cells(sh2y, 4) = sh1.Cells(5, sh1x)
   sh2.Cells(sh2y, 5) = sh1.Cells(6, sh1x)
   sh2.Cells(sh2y, 6) = sh1.Cells(7, sh1x)
   sh2.Cells(sh2y, 7) = sh1.Cells(20, sh1x)
   sh2.Cells(sh2y, 8) = sh1.Cells(21, sh1x)
End If
```

If you do it like this you have to set sh1x to the column you want to check and sh2y to the row you want it to paste to. If you want to do this automaticly, set sh1x to 2 and sh2y to 2 and just create a loop where you increase the Value of sh1x and sh2y everytime you loop (Make sure to increase the Value of them before or after the IF).